# How to automate mutt in removing old mailing-list emails?

Tags: scripting, mutt

In `mutt` I perform following sequence of steps:

```
$ mutt -f imaps://imap.example.com
username
password
[shift]+[D]
~C mailinglist1@domain.com
[shift]+[D]
~C mailinglist2@domain.com
(...)
[shift]+[D]
~C mailinglistN@domain.com

[shift]+[U]
~d<91d
q
y
```

So I :

- provide credentials `login`, `password`
- `[shift]+[D] ~C mailinglist@domain` select for deletion mailing lists *1*,*2*...*N*
- `[shift]+[U] ~d<91d` but deselect all that are less than 91d old
- `q` select quit
- `y` and confirm to delete messages

How to automate this? (make it a script)

```
mutt -e ...
```

References:

- so far I based my sequence on :

  - [Deleting all e-mail messages in your inbox with mutt
    June 19, 2009 By Major Hayden](https://major.io/2009/06/19/deleting-all-e-mail-messages-in-your-inbox-with-mutt/)
  - https://slaptijack.com/software/mutt-deleting-messages-older-than-30-days/
  - [Mutt Manual: 3. Patterns: Searching, Limiting and Tagging](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns)
- Did not figure out how to turn my steps into fully and reliably working script, but already took look at:

  - [realprogrammers.com: Mutt](http://realprogrammers.com/jump_start/mutt/)
  - [Delete Messages Containing A Keyword In Mutt](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/21-delete-messages-containing-a-keyword-in-mutt)

Comment: do you know about (and have/have access to) 'expect'?

Comment: I didn't know about `expect` ! I new about `xdotool` for X , but not about `expect` for terminal! http://expect.sourceforge.net/ Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## 1. Authentication

You can specify the username in the `imaps://` URI, and the password with the `imap_pass` configuration setting.

If you don't want to put these in your default `~/.muttrc`, you can make an alias  or shell script wrapper to run `mutt` with these settings.  e.g.

```
$ alias muttexample="mutt -f 'imaps://USERNAME@imap.example.com/' 
                          -e 'set imap_pass=PASSWORD'"
$ muttexample
```

(line feed and indentation added solely for readability)

If you are sensibly cautious and don't want the password on your command line (where it is easily visible with `ps` or by looking in `/proc`) then you can create a file called, e.g., `~/.muttrc.extra` with the following two lines:

```
source ~/.muttrc
set imap_pass=PASSWORD
```

Remember to run `chmod 600 ~/.muttrc.extra` to make it readable only by you.

Then make your alias as:

```
$ alias muttexample="mutt -f 'imaps://USERNAME@imap.example.com/' 
                          -F ~/.muttrc.extra"
```

---

## 2. Automating Deletion

Now that authentication has been solved, probably the easiest way
to automate message deletion is to use a folder-hook in `~/.muttrc.extra`.

```
source ~/.muttrc
set imap_pass=PASSWORD

folder-hook imaps://USERNAME@imap.example.com/ push 'D~Cmailinglist1@domain.com<enter>D~Cmailinglist2@domain.com<enter>D~CmailinglistN@domain.com<enter>U~d<91d<enter>qy'
```

You might need to refine the `imaps://` URI in the folder-hook - I don't use imap myself so I don't know if the `USERNAME@` portion is required in folder-hooks or not.

If that folder-hook line gets too long and complicated to edit or make sense of, you could save your commands in `~/.muttrc.deletecmds`:

```
D~Cmailinglist1@domain.com
D~Cmailinglist2@domain.com
D~CmailinglistN@domain.com
U~d<91d
qy
```

and then use this for your folder-hook:

```
folder-hook imaps://USERNAME@imap.example.com/ push `sed -z 's/\n/\<enter\>/g' ~/.muttrc.deletecmds`
```

Note that we're using backticks instead of single-quotes in the `~/.muttrc.extra` this time, to make `mutt` call an external command.

The `sed` command replaces every newline (`\n`) with the literal text `<enter>`.  It uses the `-z` option, so GNU `sed` is required.  If you don't have GNU sed, you could use `perl` or `awk` instead.

BTW, I recommend testing this on a local copy of the mailbox (adjust the mailboxes and folder-hook line etc to point to a local file rather than imap).  Save some or all of the msgs from your imap mailbox to a local mbox file if you don't have any local mail handy.

Also, I'd test without the final `qy` on the folder-hook line (or in the `~/.muttrc.deletecmds` file).  `mutt` won't quit and exit automatically, so you manually check that it's doing **exactly** what you want and nothing more.  Also you can disable writing changes to disk by typing `%` and then `qy` to quit, so you don't have to populate your testing mailbox again.

---

## 3. There are **better** ways of doing this

`mutt` really isn't the right tool for this job.

Have you considered doing this with `perl`, using the [Net::IMAP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-IMAP-Simple) module?  or one of the **many** [other modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=IMAP) `perl` has for handling IMAP and email (e.g. [Email::Simple](https://metacpan.org/release/Email-Simple))?

If you don't like `perl`, `python` a good `imaplib2` module.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution solves authentication bit. How to automate steps I perform , i.e. "selecting for deletion mailinglists & deselecting those that are newer then 91d" ? I've found that some people using `-e ` http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#set-commands commandline option to perform some things (but maybe `-e` is infeasible in my case) and some sequence after this. It seems like more straight approach then using expect like here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280089/9689 . What do you think about automating rest of steps (after authorisation) from question?

Comment: i'll have a look at the remainder of the question tomorrow if nobody else comes up with a good solution first.  i only had time to post about the authentication bit tonight.

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is to set a folder-hook for your imap folder in the ~/.muttrc.extra file.   i'll add an example to my answer